# how to create auto fit column in html where horizontal scroll bar doesn't appear irrespective of number of columns

Tags: html, css, layout, multiple-columns

I'm trying to create a html structure where the column container auto adjust width based on number of columns without horizontal scroll bar. I've tried various online resources but failed to create one.

Has any body created such structure where the width is automatically shrinks based on columns ?
[image]

[image]

something similar to this

https://vladocar.github.io/infinity-css-grid/demo1.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css grid system to reach the desired result.
Supposing you have this HTML code:

```
<div id="container" class=" col">
        <div class="element one">ONE</div>
        <div class="element two">TWO</div>
        <div class="element three">THREE</div>
        <div class="element four">Four</div>
</div>
```

Then you can write your CSS as this:

```
.element {
        padding: 1.5rem;
        border: 1px darkgray solid;
    }

    .one {
        background: rgb(121, 172, 74);
    }

    .two {
        background: rgb(71, 73, 190);
    }

    .three {
        background-color: rgb(148, 71, 71);
    }

    .four {
        background: rgb(151, 39, 142);
    }

    #container.col {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(45vh, 1fr));
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: Hey Its not working, It does not take the entire width when used. I need column or columns to take the entire width, whatever the number of columns it is.

Comment: something like this --- https://vladocar.github.io/infinity-css-grid/demo1.html

Comment: So what you want is a row(one column that takes the entire viewport width)...